# Use ModularStartup in testing project

Tags: servicestack

My testing project has grown to include many AppHost classes and having to update them all when the project changes is duplicating work so I would prefer to use modular startup on them like I do with main project.

In main project I define modular startup like so:

```cs
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseModularStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

But in my testing project I create the AppHost like this:

```cs
var appHost = new MyCustomAppHost()
                .Init()
                .Start(BaseUri);
```

and the apphost is defined like:

```cs
public class MyCustomAppHost : AppSelfHostBase
{
    public MyCustomAppHost() : base(nameof(LocalProjectAppHost), typeof(MyServices).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddUserSecrets(typeof(MyProject.Startup).Assembly);

        var configuration = builder.Build();
        
        //config here...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get modular startup working with `AppSelfHostBase`?  My goal is to be able to specify the modular config types per AppHost like so:

```cs
public class Startup : ModularStartup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) 
      : base(configuration, typeof(ConfigureRedisTesting), typeof(ConfigureCorsProduction), typeof(... etc){}
}
```

This way I can mix and match the config files I want for this specific testing apphost and will save me copy pasting all the configs into each apphost and having to maintain them separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `AppSelfHostBase` IWebHostBuilder Configuration by overriding `ConfigureHost()`. Your Startup class will also need to what the existing [AppSelfHostBase.Startup](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/862b74d6bfeacb62706b34e0e8f2ca86c5af4066/src/ServiceStack.Kestrel/AppSelfHostBase.cs#L260) does, so a custom AppHost like this should work with ServiceStack's [Modular Startup](https://docs.servicestack.net/modular-startup) feature:

```
public class AppHost : AppSelfHostBase {
    public AppHost() : base(nameof(AppHost), typeof(MyServices).Assembly) { }

    public class Startup : ModularStartup {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration, serviceTypes){}
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            HostInstance.Configuration = Configuration;
            HostInstance.Configure(services);
        }

        public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
            HostInstance.Configure(app, env);
            HostInstance.Bind(app);
            ((AppHost)HostInstance).RealInit();
        }
    }

    public override IWebHostBuilder ConfigureHost(IWebHostBuilder host, string[] urlBases) {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddUserSecrets(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
        
        return host.UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseWebRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseConfiguration(builder.Build())
            .UseUrls(urlBases);
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container) {}
}
```